# Date measures with a common scale/dimension

Tags: qliksense

I am trying to create a side-by-side bar chart where one set of bars is a count of open tickets by each week and the other set is the count of closed tickets by each week. The fields are all in a flat table.

For example, if 17 tickets were opened during week 2 (week beginning Sunday, 1/03/2016) and 14 were closed that same week (regardless of when they were created), I'd like to graph those on the same bar chart.

I am using the `Week(Opened)` function for the dimension of the first set and `Week(Closed)` as the dimension of the 2nd set. These work fine on separate bar charts. However, there is no common dimension whereby I can put them on the same chart.

I'd like to add a line to the chart as depicted in the 1st screen shot. This line is on a third scale/dimension.

I have tried a Master Calendar but my results are erroneous possibly due to the fact I have two date dimensions.

[Sample Bar Chart with line added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0BPi.png)

[Sample data screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnV7N.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a canonical date field - the full details can be found here.

https://community.qlik.com/blogs/qlikviewdesignblog/2014/02/17/canonical-date

Essentially you generate a single calendar table from the two date fields and then use the new date generated in your charts.

Comment: @PeterF not a problem, if the answer is correct please mark it as so! :)